# Elasticsearch more like this query using like_text

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having some frustration using the more like this query.

Here is my index creation:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/food/' -d 
'{
  "mappings": {
    "fruit": {
      "properties": {
        "term": {
          "type": "string",
          "term_vector": "yes"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And here is a sample piece of data in that index:

```
{
  "_index": "food",
  "_type": "fruit",
  "_id": "2",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "term": "yellow",
    "property_ids": [
      1
    ],
    "id": 2
  }
}
```

Lastly here is the more like this query I use against it to attempt to return data:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/food/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": [
        "term"
      ],
      "like_text": "yellow",
      "min_term_freq": 1,
      "max_query_terms": 12
    }
  }
}
'
```

The issue is when I do this search I get no results back:

```
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}%
```

If I do a standard wildcard query for just "yellow" I get that result back.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `min_doc_freq` is 5 ([check doc](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-mlt-query.html#_term_selection_parameters)) so, your query is not working because your index doesn't contain at least 5 documents whose `term` property holds `yellow`. So, set `min_doc_freq` to 1 in your query and it should work. Example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
            "fields": [
                "term"
             ],
             "like_text": "yellow",
             "min_term_freq": 1,
             "min_doc_freq": 1,
             "max_query_terms": 12
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly it.  Thank you very much.  I had been reading through the selection parameters and clearly didn't get far enough.  From the documentation:  min_doc_freq
 

The minimum document frequency below which the terms will be ignored from the input document. Defaults to 5.